# Post commit hook error in VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

When I commit the latest code in the TortoiseSVN Client machine, it triggers the post commit hook which has been configured in my VisualSVN Server machine.

Now the issue is: Commit is successful but i am getting an error `post-commit hook failed (exit code - 255) with no output`.

Answer (score 0):

The hook script somehow fails to process the commit. You (or your sysadmin) have to analyze what you hook script does and why it fails. There can be numerous issues. Start your troubleshooting with checking hook script's code and access permissions on the server-side.

Administrator can troubleshoot this by capturing the hook script's output for clues:

1. Rename your current `post-commit.bat` file to `post-commit-run.bat`,
2. Create the following file as your `post-commit.bat` file:

   ```
   call "%~dp0post-commit-run.bat" %* > %1/hooks/post-commit.log 2>&1
   ```
3. Commit to the repository and check the generated `post-commit.log` file in the hooks directory of your repo on server-side. The output wil give you clues about the root cause.